# Notifications at specific hour using GcmTaskService

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging, task

I need help running notifications at a specific hour of the day. I´ve searched but  found nothing.

I´me using GCMTaskService
I have a PeriodicTask that currently runs a task every 24 hours. I want it to run everyday at 4pm. any idea hpw i could do this?

Here is the periodic task as of now:

```
    long periodSecs = 86400L;
    long flexSecs = 15L;

    String tag = "periodic  | " + taskID++ + ": " + periodSecs + "s, f:" + flexSecs;  // a unique task identifier

    periodic = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setService(MyTasksService.class)
            .setPeriod(periodSecs)
            .setFlex(flexSecs)
            .setTag(tag)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .build();
    GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this).schedule(periodic);
```

This is my GCMTaskService Class:

```
public class MyTasksService extends GcmTaskService {

public MyTasksService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("myTaskService", "onBind");
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onInitializeTasks() {
    super.onInitializeTasks();
    Log.i("myTaskService", "onInitializeTasks");
}

@Override
public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    Log.i("myTaskService", "onRunTask");
    SendPushNotification.dailyNewsPush();
    SendPushNotification.dailyLecturasPush();
    return 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is hard to do is because the API is purposefully not designed for it. Hitting a server at the exact same time every day is not a good idea in terms of server load.

For e.g. if you have 1000 ppl with your app checking in with your server 1x per day your QPS will be 1000/(24 * 60 * 60) = 0.011.

If you want instead that everyone hit the server at 3pm your QPS will be 1000. This gets worse as your install base grows.

If you host your own server you will have to spin up extra capacity to deal with this huge spike, and if you rent servers you will be charged a lot to spin up instances to deal with said.

If you are doing this simply for a test app or something with a small user base it's still not a great idea as you don't know how many users you will have in the future.
However you could always compute the # of seconds until the wallclock time that you want, and use that to schedule the task.

Using the java Calendar is probably the easiest way to do this. Paraphrasing:

```
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar 3amCal = Calendar.getInstance();
3amCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
if (3amCal.before(currentCal)) {
  // it's past 3 am, roll forward
  3amCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
final long 3amTomorrow = 3amCal.getTime();
final long current = currentCal.getTime();
final long millisUntil3amTomorrow = 3amTomorrow - currentTime;
```